# AWS Cloudformation How to send logs from CloudWatch Logs to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to send EC2 logs from CloudWatch Logs to S3 using Cloudformation.
And I got a below message
Error parsing ARN from given role or target (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 357e76a9-5ade-48a6-8206-84092390602f; Proxy: null)

I don't understand which part is wrong in my code below.
Could you help me?

S3:

```
Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: vocsample01
      AccessControl: Private
```

CloudWatch Logs:

```
Type: 'AWS::Logs::Destination'
Properties:
 DestinationName: vocsample01
 DestinationPolicy: >
  {"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [
    {"Effect": "Allow","Action": "logs:*","Resource": "*"}]}
 RoleArn: arn:aws:iam::009150350157:role/vocsample
 TargetArn: arn:aws:s3:::vocsample0
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 **can't be Log destination**. Valid destinations [are](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html):

- Kinesis stream
- Firehose
- Lambda Function

If you want to load your logs to S3, you have to setup firehose first:

```
CW Logs ---> Firehose ---> S3
```